# Markov chains with Poisson

Tags: markov-chains, poisson-distribution

We have a garage that can fix 3 cars at a time and the total number of cars is 7 (3 + 4). If a vehicle comes when the garage is full then it does not get serviced. Τhe service time is exponential with an average of 6 minutes. The automobiles come with the Poisson procedure of 1 car per minute.

A) Find the probability of the garage being empty.

B) Find the mean tail length.

C) Find the actual arrival rate.

D) Find the mean of total time in the system.